# Let S be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $f$ is integrable (Riemann sense) on $S$ then $f$ is integrable on $int S.$

Tags: integration, analysis

Let S be a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If $f$ is integrable (Riemann sense) on $S$ then $f$ is integrable on $int S$ and $\int_{int~S}f = \int_Sf.$

I know this theorem using that $f$ is continuous. To prove that is true without this hypothesis seems a little hard.

What I thought was something like: $$\text{$f$ is integrable} \Rightarrow |\partial S| = 0,$$ where $|\partial S| = 0$ means that the boundary of $S$ has null measure.

Now, once $S = int ~S \cup \partial S$and this is a disjoint union,

$$\int_S f = \int_{int~S}f + \int_{\partial S}f = \int_{int~ S}f~ \text{once $|\partial S| = 0$}.$$

Is this right?

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that $f$ is riemann integrable iff it is continuous almost everywhere?

Comment: @AlexR., yes! I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $S=C\cup D$, where $C$ are the points of continuity, and $D$ is $S \setminus C$. Our theorem on Riemann integrability assures that $C$ is Lebesgue measurable, and since $S$ is assumed to be, then so is $D$. Now let $C_i = int(S)\cap C$ and $D_i = int(S) \cap D$ (which again are measurable). Finally let $C_b = C \setminus C_i \subseteq \partial S$ and $D_b = D \setminus D_i \subseteq \partial S$. Note that all our sets are disjoint, and their union is $S$, furthermore $int(S) = C_i \cup D_i$.Then we can make the following calculation for $f$ Riemann measurable:

\begin{align*}
 \int_S f d\mu &= \int_C f d\mu +\int_D fd\mu = \int_{C_i} fd \mu +\underbrace{\int_{D} f d\mu}_{=0}\\
&= \int_{C_i} f d\mu + \underbrace{\int_{D_i} f d\mu}_{=0} +\underbrace{\int_{D_b} fd\mu}_{=0} =  \int_{C_i} f d\mu +\int_{D_i} f d \mu\\
&= \int_{int(S)} f d\mu.
\end{align*}